# How to get more than one value from a key in .property

Tags: java, jar

I got a .property file with many user information, I want to get all the users name in a array, but .getProperty only return me the last one, should I use a for each or is there any another way to make it?

```
            prop = new Properties();

            prop.load(new FileInputStream("resource/GenLoadFlowEnv.properties"));

   String env = (prop.getProperty("ambiente"));
```

Comment: Properties extends Map: it associates **unique** keys with a value. So you can't have two equal keys in a properties file.

Comment: As Jb Njzet stated property cannot be duplicate. If you want to iterate over property file then use buffer reader and read line.  And use substring to get the Value of each user as the key remains same else use comma separated user list for the property ambiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply place

```
ambiente = a,b,c
```

And than get the array

```
String env = (prop.getProperty("ambiente"));
String[] arr = env.split(",");
```

Comment: You should add that this approach (manually encoding multiple values into one string) is actually the only way to solve this requirement.

Comment: @GhostCat no, it's not the only way. You could simply use user.0, user.1, user.2, etc. as keys and iterate over keys that start with user, for example.